# What gambling/board game or real life thing can (surprisingly) be modelled as a linear programming problem?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, puzzle, linear-programming, operations-research, gambling

So I've taken Linear Programming 101.

I've read my textbook, took the test and all that, and - besides all the theory, the nice algebraic interpretations, etc - I've encountered a lot of textbook examples of linear programming problems.

You know, the usual, the diet problem, the transportation problem, the usual "a factory makes 300 screws and 400 bolts a day, McGyver is trapped in the factory and..." problem.

I wonder if there is some interesting example beyond that from real life or puzzles/card/board games that can be interpreted/modelled as a nice, elegant, perhaps even beautiful (but still nice and simple) linear programming problem.

I can't think of any, can you?

Bonus points if it uses duality.

I don't think I want to see the complete model, unless a lot of thought is required, though - you could as well leave me the fun of that or maybe just throw me a clue :)

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for in an answer. I'm giving you a couple of really neat cutting edge problems concerning transportation, but it is sometimes _surprising_ that linear programming can handle such large problems in practice.

Comment: You know - when I stumbled upon this, I went "A-AH!": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#Linear_programming_formulation
Something relatively familiar has a simple linear programming model. Who whould have thought.
Now - I wonder if I can "A-AH!" again :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linear programming is widely used in all sorts of fun transportation problems. These problems are not *simple*, but they are *useful* and *interesting*. An example off the top of my head: how do you effectively allocate [bikes](https://www.capitalbikeshare.com/) or [cars](http://www.zipcar.com/) as a public resource?

#### Publicly available papers:

[Balancing Bike Sharing Systems with Constraint Programming](http://www.tunnuz.net/documents/digaspero_rendl_urli_constraints2014.pdf)

[Decision support for tactical resource allocation in bike sharing systems](https://www.tu-braunschweig.de/Medien-DB/winfo/publications/decision_support_for_tactical_resource_allocation_in_bike_sharing_systems.pdf)

[Locating Stations for
Bicycle-Sharing Schemes](http://www.ms.unimelb.edu.au/documents/thesis/ThesisVictoriaWyatt.pdf)

[Balancing Bicycle Sharing Systems:
A Variable Neighborhood Search Approach?](https://www.ads.tuwien.ac.at/publications/bib/pdf/rainer-harbach-13a.pdf)

[The vehicle relocation problem for the one-way electric vehicle sharing](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.7195.pdf)

[Optimizing Locations for a Vehicle Sharing System](http://transp-or.epfl.ch/documents/proceedings/Kumar_STRC_2012.pdf)

Comment: Hah, nice!
I find it hardly "pretty" or suprising (maybe because I pass by a bike sharing station every day on my way home and I always guessed they did some LP on that), but the papers themselves are pretty interesting.
Thanks!

Comment: BTW - upvoted but not accepted because it isn't quite what I'm looking for (see comment for my OP) - but it's cool nonetheless :)